Change Group By in a Power BI Chart
in Power BI, I have a clustered Bar Chart.
By default, it groups by Date.  Is there anyway, that I can group all of the "Brand Mentions" together, Domain Mentioned together etc?
I've included a picture (last picture below), where it shows what I'd like it to look like (this was easy in Excel).
Thanks, Mark




Are you using a cluster column chart in Power BI?

UPDATE:
Your data:

Highlight Date and unpivot other:

Updated data table:


Hi David - yes I am - I just can't seem to find anywhere to group differently.

Drag date to your legend, brand mentions to your x-axis and then your measure to the y-axis

If you want them all to show, you will need to unpivot your data in Power Query and use the two new columns for that. Click Date and unpivot other rows.

Hi David - it's not a pivot table to begin with - just a simple table with the categories as column headers, and the dates being the left most column (as per the table screenshot in the post).
I did try  dragging the date to the legend and brand mentions to the x-axis - but I also was looking for the other cateogories to be present too. Thanks.

I know it is not a pivot table. However, in Power Query, you need to unpivot your data. I'll paste a screenshot
